# Авторизация с дополнительной проверкой

Tags: php, laravel5

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста по такому вопросу: Добавил для пользователей столбец is_active. Как при аутентификации проверять это поле и если оно 0, то не давать пользователю войти на сайт?
И второй момент - как разлогинеть тех пользователей, кому в базе проставлен 0, но которые авторизированы на сайте?
(laravel 5.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Auth делаем что-то вроде этого

```
public function postLogin() {
    // Формируем базовый набор данных для авторизации
    // (isActive => 1 нужно для того, чтобы аторизоваться могли только
    // активированные пользователи)
    $creds = array(
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'isActive'  => 1,
    );


// Пытаемся авторизовать пользователя
if (Auth::attempt($creds, Input::has('remember'))) {
    Log::info("User [{$username}] successfully logged in.");
    return Redirect::intended();
} else {
    Log::info("User [{$username}] failed to login.");
}

$alert = "Неверная комбинация имени и пароля, либо учетная запись еще не активирована.";
return Redirect::back()->withAlert($alert);
```

}

Подробнее и пошагово что и как делать расписано [здесь](http://amegatron.ru/2014/07/poetapnaya-razrabotka-sajta-na-laravel-4-urok-5-chast-2/)